# SQL Server connection problem

Tags: c#, sql-server

I added an external Data Source to my C# app (I've placed it on the root directory in a folder named 'data') but when I run the program I get an error at `con.Open()`:

`An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\alex\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Network_Remote_Monitoring\Network_Remote_Monitoring\bin\Debug\data\bd.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.`

Here is my source code :

```
 con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Data       Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\data\\bd.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
            ds1 = new DataSet();
            ds2 = new DataSet();

            con.Open();

            string sql = "SELECT * From localitati";
            da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
            da.Fill(ds1, "localitati");

            sql = "SELECT * From sucursale";
            da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
            da.Fill(ds1, "sucursale");

            con.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a same problem as this question: [connect to .mdf file in vs2010 , wpf application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076232/connect-to-mdf-file-in-vs2010-wpf-application/4076320#4076320)
I answer it there, but it's just my guess. because it is usual problem.

Comment: when i replace the connectionString with the actual path it works. My question is if i develop an app, how can i refference the db ? i mean something like ".//app//db.mdf"?

Comment: and btw , in the app.config i've changed the connectionString to "blabla" and it still worked( the db connection) .. is that string rellevant to anything?

Comment: @Badescu Alexandru, You can put your DB behind executable file, and no other path, Also you can put it in everywhere and set system path for it, So when it .Net searchs for paths it will be find it.

Answer (score 0):

Does the account that is running your application have access to the data folder?

Comment: i'm not very familiar to db so if you could be more specific ? i've encoutered a "log onto server " ( when adding a new connection) but i left the Defaut ( Use windows autentification )